# How to effectively write METADATA to GeoTIFF with GDAL utils other than gdal_translate

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, metadata

I can write some [metadata to GeoTIFF](https://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html) with [gdal_translate](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) using -mo, example:

```
gdal_translate in.tif out.tif -mo TIFFTAG_ARTIST="It was me" -mo TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION="This data my layer"
```

I suppose that it should be possible to do the same job with other GDAL v2.x utils (gdalwarp, gdal_calc.py, etc.), but I could not find, how. Is there such option?

OR

Should I always use gdal_translate for this job?

The problem with gdal_translate is that it always creates a NEW file. I work with large GeoTIFFs. So just to add some lines of metadata takes o lot of time. Is there a way just to add Metadata to GeoTIFF without re-creating it again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`gdal_edit.py`](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_edit.html):

```
gdal_edit.py -mo TIFFTAG_ARTIST="It was me" in.tif
```